# How do I prevent default tab switching functionality in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the tabs below.

```
<ul class="idTabs">
<li><a href="#basic_info" id="basic_info_link" >Personal</a></li>
<li><a href="#add_info" id="add_info_link">Address</a></li>
<li style="width:194px;"><a href="#payment_info" id="payment_link" style="border-left:none;width:194px;">Bank</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="basic_info"><!--HTML Code --></div>
<div id="add_info"><!--HTML Code --></div>
<div id="payment_info"><!--HTML Code --></div>
```

The tabs work fine, but the problem is that on clicking these tabs heading I want to prevent to go to next tab.

Comment: so let me summarize. you are using jQuery tabs? and you want to prevent the default tab switch functionality so that you can use your tab switcher? am i right?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.idTabs li a').on('click', function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QLM2s/4/)***

Comment: You can also set the href attribute to `javascript:void(0);`

Comment: @thecodeparadox: I am having the same case except, I am validating data first. If validation false it should not redirect to clicked tab. But `e.preventDefault();` does not work for me. Any help?